# Set interpretation with break line

Tags: math-mode, align, mathtools

I want to write the following set

```
\begin{align*}
\{ d \in \mathcal{D}^* | 
\begin{split}
F(S_1,\ldots,S_k) \land \bigwedge_{i = 1}^k S_i = \set{ n \in \N ; \varphi_i(d(n)) } \land \\ \exists \overline{t} \in P(L_1,\ldots,L_n). \bigwedge_{i = 1}^k S_i = \set{ n \in \N ; t_i(n) } 
\end{split}
\}
\end{align*}
```

The problem is that the braces and middle line don't scale automatically.

I was using the following command to define sets

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]{\{}{\}}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1} {#1\nonscript\:\delimsize\vert\allowbreak\nonscript\:\mathopen{}#2}}
\def\Set{\set*}
```

But I'm not sure how to adapt this to my usecase.

Comment: Please combine the two sniplets to a single minimal example.

Comment: `\left \{ ... \middle \vert ... \right\}` (untested with the actual code as there is no complete MWE)